# Hotel sign horizontally flipped

Tags: kaleido-star

In episode 5, at around 5:13 mark, we see the car driving away from the camera. On the right the "HOTEL" sign is drawn horizontally flipped. Could it be that in real life such sign exists, or is this just a drawing error?

[image]

Comment: Where did you watch this?  If it was something on YouTube, it is common practice to mirror the image to avoid automatic copyright detection.  If that (or something similar) isn't the case, it would be good to rule that out.

Comment: I own the DVD..

Comment: The car also looks like it's driving on the right.  I wonder if this was done to appeal to a largely American audience?  (They'd be confused if the car were on the left, and a simple mirror is a good way to get around that.)

Comment: @Makoto That seemed like the likely culprit to me too, but I checked the Japanese BD and it turns out that there isn't any flipping going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this scene isn't happening in Japan, it's in Los Angeles, where Kaleido Stage itself is located, so it makes sense the car is on the right side.

While I do not have a definitive answer, there are two likely explanations:

1. During the production, while creating the scene they realized midway
   or after its completion that it isn't in Japan, so they flipped the
   background or the whole scene around.
2. The background was originally meant for cars coming towards the
   viewer, not for ones going away from us, so they flipped it around
   and didn't notice the sign or didn't have time to correct it.

The actual answer is more likely to be (or to be closer to) the latter, as the cars parking on the right side are actually on the wrong side of the road, their fronts are pointed towards the screen (If you don't have a driving license: in most countries this is considered illegal, [including Los Angeles](http://www.californiadriving.com/parking/)). Also, their driving wheels are on the right side instead of the left, while it's on the correct side in the police car a few seconds earlier. (But of course, this could be a production error too.)

[image: x]